# How can I have fixedSize Textfield in macOS SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using this down code to having a fixedSize Textfield in order to see all string in Textfield:

```
struct TextFieldView: View {
    
    @Binding var string: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return TextField("", text: $string)
            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
            .fixedSize()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(3.0)
            .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(4.0))
    }
    
}
```

When I use this code and I type to fill string, it does not work, it disable typing function because of .fixedSize(), secondly when I gave a value via Binding it allow to type but it has issue in animation in jump front and back in each single type also not pleasant and good typing functionality. I am not saying my approach is the way to go, but I am looking to have a textField that shows all it strings, and it cannot be smaller than its String length. How can i have such a design?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve, would you elaborate more?

Comment: @Asperi: If I have a TextField with a string, I can resize the Window size and along Window the TextField would be get smaller and smaller, I want stop that, in this way that TextField cannot get smaller than the length of it's string. that is why I tried to use fixedSize.